# create a summary table with count values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, aggregate-functions

my df looks like

```
group   value
A       1

B       1

A       1

B       1

B       0

B       0

A       0
```

I want to create a df

```
value   0      1
group
A       a      b
B       c      d
```

where a,b,c,d are the counts of 0s and 1s in groups A and B respectively.

I tried group `df.groupby('group').size()` but that gave an overall count and did not split 0's and 1s. I tried a groupby count method too but have not been able to achieve the target data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```
pd.crosstab(df['group'], df['value'])
```

Output:

```
value  0  1
group      
A      1  2
B      2  2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use pivot table for this:

```
res = pd.pivot_table(df, index='group', columns='value', aggfunc='size')

>>>print(res)
value  0  1
group
A      1  2
B      2  2
```